# Android - Generic Class as return type in Kotlin for Retrofit call

Tags: android, kotlin, generics, retrofit2

I have the following method :

```
override suspend fun getData(pageNr: Int): NetworkResult {
    
    // make the request
    val response = getDataApi.getData(pageNr)
    
    // based on response, return either Success or Error
    return if(response.isSuccessful){
         NetworkResult.Success(response.body())
    } else{
         NetworkResult.Error(response.code())
    }
}
```

Android Studio complains about the return type. It says:

```
"One type argument expected for class NetworkResult<out R>"
```

My `NetworkResult.kt` is as follows:

```
sealed class NetworkResult<out R> {

    data class Success<out T>(val data: T) : NetworkResult<T>()
    data class Error(val errorCode: Int) : NetworkResult<Nothing>()
    object Loading : NetworkResult<Nothing>()

    override fun toString(): String {
        return when (this) {
            is Success<*> -> "Success[data=$data]"
            is Error -> "Error[code=$errorCode]"
            Loading -> "Loading"
        }
    }
}
```

Why this error is popping up ? `Success` and `Error` are both subtypes of `NetworkResult`...so why is returning one of them not allowed ?

For the sake of completeness, I also added Retrofit interface call method:

```
@GET("getData/")
suspend fun getData(@Query("page") page:Int) : Response<MyData>
```

Comment: Your `NetworkResult<out R>` has a type parameter `R` you need to specify that in your function signature. So whatever type `response.body()` has, that you need to specify in the getData signature.

Comment: return type of response.body() is MyData.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add generic parameter to returning type of `getData` function:

```
override suspend fun getData(pageNr: Int): NetworkResult<MyData> {
    // ...
}
```

You can either change generic type to `MyData?` or if you are sure `response.body()` doesn't return `null`, add `!!` operator: `NetworkResult.Success(response.body()!!)`

Comment: but the else condition does not return a MyData instance. Instead, with response.error() an Int value is returned

Comment: that's ok, it returns `Nothing`, `Nothing` inherits other classes, including `MyData` class.

Comment: android studio now complains that "Required: NetworkResult<MyData>" and "Found : NetworkResult.Success<MyData?>" .
The whole if-else branch is underlined with red.

Comment: ok, I decided to use !! and added a try/catch block around it.